# MVVM architecture problem when trying to get my item details?

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture

Here I am not asking for code problem, but just architecture, I will show what Iof course.

So I was just playing around with this MVVM architecture, I was displaying a list of items, I click an item I see its details, there are many categories in those details, meaning that for example I had a personal data displayed in one cardview, informations about his credit card for example in an other cardview, etc.. For some Users who are connected, credit cards data must not be displayed, but when I created the view model in the begging it was like this :

```
public class ContractViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public MutableLiveData<ContractModel> contract = new MutableLiveData<ContractModel>();
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> isLoading = new MutableLiveData<Boolean>();
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> error = new MutableLiveData<Boolean>();

    @Inject
    ContractService contractService;

    CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    public ContractViewModel(){
        DaggerContractApiComponent.create().inject(this);
    }

    public void call(SingleContractRequest singleContractRequest){
        fetchContract(singleContractRequest);
    }

    public void fetchContract(SingleContractRequest singleContractRequest){

        isLoading.setValue(true);

        disposable.add(
                contractService.getContract(singleContractRequest)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<ContractModel>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(ContractModel contractModel) {
                                isLoading.setValue(false);
                                error.setValue(false);
                                contract.setValue(contractModel);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                error.setValue(true);
                                isLoading.setValue(false);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared(){
        super.onCleared();
        disposable.clear();
    }
}
```

But now I need the user connected role in the app to display the possible data that he can consult. The first thought coming to my head was just calling the service that return my userConnected.

```
public class ContractViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public MutableLiveData<ContractModel> contract = new MutableLiveData<ContractModel>();
    public MutableLiveData<UserConnected> userConnected = new MutableLiveData<UserConnected>();
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> isLoading = new MutableLiveData<Boolean>();
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> error = new MutableLiveData<Boolean>();

    @Inject
    ContractService contractService;

    @Inject
    UserConnectedService userConnectedService;

    CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    public ContractViewModel(){
        DaggerContractApiComponent.create().inject(this);
        DaggerUserConnectedApiComponent.create().inject(this);
    }

    public void call(SingleContractRequest singleContractRequest){
        fetchContract(singleContractRequest);
    }


    public void getUserConnected(){
        disposable.add(
                userConnectedService.getUserConnected()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<UserConnected>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UserConnected userConnectedParams) {
                                userConnected.setValue(userConnectedParams);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                            }


                        })
        );
    }

    public void fetchContract(SingleContractRequest singleContractRequest){

        isLoading.setValue(true);

        disposable.add(
                contractService.getContract(singleContractRequest)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<ContractModel>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(ContractModel contractModel) {
                                isLoading.setValue(false);
                                error.setValue(false);
                                contract.setValue(contractModel);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                error.setValue(true);
                                isLoading.setValue(false);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared(){
        super.onCleared();
        disposable.clear();
    }
}
```

But it is not clean, I have to call two methods at the same time in my Activity, which is terrible, the second thought is that I have to edit my `contract` type from `MutableLiveData<ContractModel>` to something like this `MutableLiveData<NewModel>` knowing that this NewModel architecture is like this :

```
public NewModel {
    ContractModel contractModel;
    UserModel userModel;

    // ofc here a constuctor and getters and setters

}
```

But this has a problem too that will be caused in the backend, because what if I need the userConnected in an other activity ? I will have to write similar code in multiple places to get this userConnected, but I want to get it once.

Any help, thoughts would be really helpful.

Comment: Is userConnected going to change so often to explain you having to fetch it so many times? Maybe you can make a call to retrieve it at app start, and then cache it.

Comment: No, it not going to change many times

Comment: I think yeah, I will try to get in app start

Comment: Yeah, write a "UserConnected" singleton helper, to manage storing and retrieving it from sharedPreferences.